# How to add more items at run time in spinner

Tags: android, spinner

if we has a some items in the spinner means (like below) how shall we add extra items while run time

here is code:

```
    String[] Items = {
                "Alarm",
                "Office",
                "Meeting",
                "Party",
                "Lunch",
                "Breakfast",
                "Supper",
                "Home",
                "Private",
                "Outdoor",
                "Family",
                "Friends",
                "Others"
        };

    Spinner s1;
```

and

```
  s1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);

   ArrayAdapter<String> adapter  = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
            this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,Items);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    s1.setAdapter(adapter);
    s1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener()
    {
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, 
        View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) 
        {
            int index = s1.getSelectedItemPosition();
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), 
                "You have selected item : " + Items[index], 
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 

            if (index==12)
            {
                EditText edit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edittext);
                Button add=(Button) findViewById(R.id.add);
                edit.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                add.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);


         }
            else
            {
                EditText edit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edittext);
                Button add=(Button) findViewById(R.id.add);
                edit.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                add.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        }

        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {}
    });  

}
```

In it if select the "other" means we ve to add extra items in spinner list..

thank you,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I hope you can detect the case when the user has selected "others"

in that case, add the other values in your Items array and call the function `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` it should accommodate the changes and you should see the new values in the spinner.

try this out and revert.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a [BaseAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html), fill it in runtime and assign the adapter to the spinner.

Comment: You're right! He can merge the two solutions changing the baseAdapter and notifying to the spinner with notifyDataSetChanged. am I right?

Answer (score 0):

Following works for me:

```
/* Read values from resource into an array */
String[] strColorValues =  getResources().getStringArray(R.array.colors);

ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
for (int i = 0; i < strColorValues.length; i++) {
    list.add(strColorValues[i]);
}

ArrayAdapter adapterColors = new ArrayAdapter(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list);

adapterColors.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

spinnerColors.setAdapter(adapterPermissionLevels);
spinnerColors.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

/* Remove first element from the adapter and notify dataset changed. */
String item = spinnerColors.getItemAtPosition(0).toString();
adapterColors.remove(item);
adapterColors.notifyDataSetChanged();
```